# Writing OPC - need some advice

Tags: plc, opc

Im using free fatrat library to create server and i have a few question:

- On server site i think that I only need to do is give parameter about server like clsid, description, version and create branches and leafs, am I wrong? I dont know either if branch means group and leaf item?
- If i want to get from PLC data for example 10 000 Real and 10 000 Bool values, that means i must create 10 000 leafs for real and 10 000 leafs for bool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the address space a branch is kind of a group and leaf is an item, i.e. variable.